# IBM AppDOS.ConnectionClose vulnerability

Tags: java

IBM Appscan source scanner detected AppDOS.ConnectionClose vulnerability in below source.

I fixed the issue by closing the connection in finally block but still it is reporting the same. Is there any pattern to close db connection?

```
Connection nCnn = null;

try
{
    nCnn = getConnection();

    /* some database operation */


    nCnn.close() /* Reporting AppDOS.ConnectionClose vulnerability */ 


} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new SQLException("Connection close", e);
}
finally
{
    try {
        if (nCnn != null)

            nCnn.close(); /* Reporting AppDOS.ConnectionClose vulnerability */ 

    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fix should have mitigated the issue. The fact that Appscan Source is still reporting the issue after the fix is likely a defect. A mitigation example by Appscan Source is as follows:

```
try
{
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(some_connection_string);
} catch (Exception e) {
    log(e);
} finally {
    connection.close();
}
```